# No suitable constructor was found for entity type "MyEntity"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

Basically im trying to setup Entity Framework Core for the first time ever. When i try to migrate the initial db creation in the package manager console i get the error message:

```
The specified type 'ChatBot.Models.IParticipant' must be a non-interface reference type to be used as an entity type.
```

Class code:

```
  public Conversation() { }
    public Conversation(Guid id)
    {
        ID = id;
        Status = ConversationStatus.ONGOING;
    }

    public Conversation(Guid id, ConversationStatus status, SortedSet<Message> messages, ISet<IParticipant> participants)
    {
        ID = id;
        Status = status;
        Messages = messages;
        Participants = participants;
    }

    public Guid ID { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    // Sorted by the timestamp of the messages
    // See Message.CompareTo() method for more info
    public SortedSet<Message> Messages
    {
        get => new(_messages);
        set => _messages = value;
    }

    public ConversationStatus Status { get; private set; }

    public DateTime StartTime => _messages.First().Timestamp;

    public DateTime? EndTime
    {
        get
        {
            if (Status == ConversationStatus.ONGOING)
                return null;
            else
                return _messages.Last().Timestamp;
        }
    }

    public ISet<IParticipant> Participants
    {
        get => new HashSet<IParticipant>(_participants);
        set => _participants = value;
    }

 private SortedSet<Message> _messages = new();
    private ISet<IParticipant> _participants = new HashSet<IParticipant>();
```

I have tried to override the OnModelCreating method in my database context class:

```
 public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Conversation> Chats { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TicketDTO> Participants { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Entity<Conversation>(builder =>
        {
            builder.HasKey(c => c.ID);
            builder.HasMany(c => c.Messages);
            builder.HasMany(c => c.Participants);
        });
    }
```

Note: IParticipant interface only contains a Guid

Answer (score 0):

EF requires a parameterless constructor. When pulling data from the context, it creates an empty object, then uses the public properties to populate it with data.

Bit of a pain sometimes, but you can see why they do it that way.

Comment: I do have one. That's not the issue. Entity framework requires a non-interface reference type. In my constructor, I have an ISet<IParticipant>.  The IParticipant is the issue.

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question to include the paramterless ctor. However, assuming you have one, then the only thing I can think of it to create a ctor for each concrete type you have that implements your interface. Depending on how many classes implement it, this may be easy, it may be a pain, but I can't think of any other answer at the moment.

Comment: Also, the error message you quote in your question says quite clearly that it needs a parameterless constructor, so I'm not sure why you think the interface is the issue. Please clarify the question, as the way it looks now, my answer is correct. If there is something you aren't showing (code or error messages), then you need to add them.

Comment: It would also help if you include the full code for your model, as the last line of the error message you quote sounds like you're trying to include navigation properties in your ctor, which it doesn't like.

Comment: I have updated the code and the error message